# AWS Cloud Cost Explorer: Get more than 12 months of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

How to get data more than 12 months of data in AWS Cost Explorer?

I am try to fetch data more than 12 months as per customer or client requirements. My task is to fetch data mapped resources, with comparison of credit, tax, refund amount.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that only twelve months of historical data is available in Cost Explorer [according to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-what-is.html).

AWS does send detailed invoices via email each month that should have the same data that's available in Cost Explorer, albeit in PDF format.